# What is the difference between immutable and const variables in Rust?

Tags: rust, constants, immutability

I learned that if a variable is not explicitly declared mutable using `mut`, it becomes immutable (it cannot be changed after declaration). Then why do we have the `const` keyword in Rust? Aren't they the same? If not, how do they differ?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`const`, in Rust, is short for *constant* and is related to *compile-time evaluation*. It shows up:

- when declaring constants: `const FOO: usize = 3;`
- when declaring compile-time evaluable functions: `const fn foo() -> &'static str`

These kinds of values can be used as generic parameters: `[u8; FOO]`. For now this is limited to array size, but there is talk, plans, and hope to extend it further in the future.

By contrast, a `let` binding is about a run-time computed value.

Note that despite `mut` being used because the concept of mutability is well-known, Rust actually lies here. `&T` and `&mut T` are about aliasing, not mutability:

- `&T`: shared reference
- `&mut T`: unique reference

Most notably, some types feature *interior mutability* and can be mutated via `&T` (shared references): `Cell`, `RefCell`, `Mutex`, etc.

---

*Note: there is an alternative use of `mut` and `const` with raw pointers (`*mut T` and `*const T`) which is not discussed here.*

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html - here is the raw pointer usage It also gets a mention here.. https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html - but that isn't so easy to follow.

Comment: This accepted answer is too complex for newbies like me. Please see below answer by snnsnn for better understanding.

Comment: I don't think this answer actually answered the question at all. The question asks for diff, you go straightly to explain the diff, instead of putting in a lot of irrelevant content.

Answer (score 37):

`const` is not for variables; it's for constant values which may not be stored anywhere; they're effectively an alias for a literal value.

Non-`mut` `let` declares an actual variable which is created at runtime, can be moved (and no longer accessible), and even have interior mutability (if it contains `Cell` members, for example) in some cases.

Answer (score 24):

A `const` does not represent a memory location but a value. `const` values are directly inlined at their usage location. Any temporary objects that are created during expression evaluation are accessible only by the compiler during compile time. Can be scoped globally. Can not reference runtime items. Must be type annotated.

Let values represent a memory location. Immutability for `let` binding is a compiler enforced thing that can be changed with the `mut` modifier. It is runtime construct. Always locally scopped. Their types can be inferred by the compiler.

For completeness, a `static` also represents a memory location like let but any references to the same static are actually a reference to the same memory location. Statics are, well, statics. They are compiled into the executable and are accessible for the entire lifetime of the running program. Can be scoped globally. Can reference other statics. Must be type annotated.

Comment: But why developers who created Rust wanted to create both of them instead of using `let` in all places? What is the reasoning of inventing `const` in the first place?

Comment: Performance. const produce more performant code but it is less flexible as there is no way to change the value. So, it is advised to use const whenever possible.

Answer (score 16):

Constants can not be [**shadowed**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html#shadowing):

```
let x = 10u32;
const Y:u32 = 20u32;

let x = 11u32;
//error: duplicate definition of value `Y` [E0428]
//const Y:u32 = 21u32;

println!("x={} Y={}",x,Y); //x=11 Y=20
```

Answer (score 8):

Additionally, we can't make global items using *let*, but it's possible by using *const*. Here is an example.

```
const LENGTH:usize = 4;

fn main() {
    let arr:[i32; LENGTH] = [10,20,30,40];

    for i in 0..LENGTH{
        println!("{}", arr[i])
    }
}
```

---

for more information about the usages of *const*, *static*, and *let*:
[`const` and `static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.1.0/book/const-and-static.html)

The story is a little bit longer.

Answer (score 3):

`const` is for compile-time constants with everything that entails. For example, you can create a fixed-sized array whose size is a `const`, but you can't do that with a `let` binding. Of course, this also means that you can put far, far more things into a `let` binding than into a `const`.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, `const` items are substituted before parsing, akin to what a C-macro does. This enables it to be used in circumstances where normal variables are not allowed.

```rust
const TEN: u32 = 10;
let ten = 10;

// OK
match x {
    TEN => do_a(),
    _ => do_b(),
}

// Nah...
match x {
    ten => do_a(),
    _ => do_b(),
}

// ...use this instead
match x {
    y if x == ten => do_a(),,
    _ => do_b(),
}
```