# Why does taking a static reference to a const return a reference to a temporary variable?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

In Rust I have the following code:

```
pub trait Test: Sized {
    const CONST: Self;
    fn static_ref() -> &'static Self {
        &Self::CONST
    }
}
```

My expectation is that since `const` is `'static`, then I should be able to take a reference to it that is also `'static`. However, the compiler gives the following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
   --> file.rs:9:9
    |
  9 |         &Self::CONST
    |         ^-----------
    |         ||
    |         |temporary value created here
    |         returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

How is a temporary variable being introduced here?

Additionally, it seems that there are some cases where taking a reference to a constant does work. Here is a short concrete example with a slightly different implementation of Test

```
pub trait Test: Sized {
    fn static_ref() -> &'static Self;
}

struct X;

impl Test for X {
    fn static_ref() -> &'static Self {
        &X
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to extend the lifetime of CONST over the lifetime of the function. When you exit function, the reference to CONST isn't valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const`  and `static` are different things, but are often confused with each other.

`static` bindings hold data that lives in a permanent memory location for the duration of the program. That's why you can return references to them from functions; they live forever so you can give them the `'static` lifetime.

`const` bindings have values that don't change and can be reasoned about at compile-time just as well as at run-time. The compiler will inline the expression used to define the `const` everywhere that it is used. It's likely that two usages of the same constant will store it in different memory addresses and *may* even reapply the computation used to construct it.

Consider a slightly more complicated example:

```
struct MyStruct;

impl MyStruct {
    const fn new() -> Self {
        MyStruct
    }
}

impl Test for MyStruct {
    const CONST: Self = MyStruct::new();
}
```

This won't work because, since constants are inlined, the implementation of `static_ref` will now look like this:

```
fn static_ref() -> &'static Self {
    &MyStruct::new()
}
```

It's creating a value inside the function and trying to return it. This value is *not* static, so the `'static` lifetime is invalid.

---

However, with a little re-jigging, you can make something work:

```
pub trait Test: Sized + 'static {
    // This is now a reference instead of a value:
    const CONST: &'static Self;

    fn static_ref() -> &'static Self {
        Self::CONST
    }
}

struct MyStruct;

impl MyStruct {
    const fn new() -> Self {
        MyStruct
    }
}

impl Test for MyStruct {
    const CONST: &'static Self = &MyStruct::new();
}
```

This works because `CONST` is already a `'static` reference, so the function can just return it. All possible implementations would have to be able to obtain a `'static` reference to `Self` to implement the trait, so there is no longer an issue with referencing a temporary value.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks. Yes, that wasn't quite right! I've made some changes, but feel free to edit.

Answer (score 13):

A *constant* in Rust is a compile-time constant, not an actual variable with a memory location. The Rust compiler can substitute the actual *value* of the constant whereever it is used. If you take the address of such a value, you get the address of a temporary.

Rust also has the concept of a *static variable*. These variables actually have memory locations that are consistent for the whole program duration, and taking a reference to a static variable indeed results in a reference with `'static` lifetime.

See also:

- [What is the difference between immutable and const variables in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877381/what-is-the-difference-between-immutable-and-const-variables-in-rust)
- [What is the difference between a const variable and a static variable and which should I choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52751597/what-is-the-difference-between-a-const-variable-and-a-static-variable-and-which/52753798)

Comment: This seems inconsistent with some of the documenation. By way of example, I can do this...impl Test for X {
    fn static_ref() -> &'static Self {
        &X{}
    }
} In this example, the value X{} is a constant, and yet I take a reference to it.

Comment: I will edit the question to add this additional wrinkle.

Comment: @ZacharyBurns I can't follow the example you gave in the comment. I suggest asking a new question if this one wasn't enough, or at least giving a playground link for the example, so we can follow it. It would also be helpful to give a pointer to the documentation you think is wrong.

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify how it is sometimes possible to take a reference to a constant. I am looking for the documentation and will update the comment shortly.

Comment: what's a temporary?

Comment: @joel A temporary is an anonymous intermediate result in an expression which only live for the duration of the current statement.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism at work here is static promotion.
See [RFC 1414](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.md)

Here's a quote:

> Inside a function body's block:
>
> - If a shared reference to a constexpr rvalue is taken. (&)
> - And the constexpr does not contain a UnsafeCell { ... } constructor.
> - And the constexpr does not contain a const fn call returning a type
>   containing a UnsafeCell.
> - Then instead of translating the value into a
>   stack slot, translate it into a static memory location and give the
>   resulting reference a 'static lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

I think the three answers above, each addresses only one aspect of the question. The answer from Sven Marnach explains why the first example does not work.

The bigger question is: Why does the second example with "struct X" work? The answer is "static promotion" that Bockwurst pointed out.

But then again, the question is why does not the following example from Peter Hall work?

```rust
  fn static_ref() -> &'static Self {
    // &Self::CONST
    &MyStruct::new()
  }
```

Note that, this code does not compile even if there is no trait implementation:

```rust
// Complete example that does not compile.
struct MyStruct;
impl MyStruct {
    const fn new() -> Self {
        MyStruct
    }
    fn static_ref() -> &'static Self {
        &MyStruct::new()
    }
}
```

I think that is because although `new` is a `const fn`, it is not called in a const context. If we change `static_ref` to the following, then the code compiles:

```rust
  fn static_ref() -> &'static Self {
    const RESULT: &MyStruct = &MyStruct::new();
    RESULT
  }
```

But this does not solve the original problem in trait `Test`. This is because, as others pointed out, the compiler will substitute the actual value of the constant, and there is no guarantee that for all implementations of the trait, this value will be promotable to static.

Answer (score 1):

This *should* work, contrary to other answers here. The reason it does not work is subtle.

The problem is that the value cannot be [promoted](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/destructors.html#constant-promotion). But why?

We can get a better error by forcing the compiler to promote it (this is using the unstable [inline const](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76001) for convenience; this can also be done using associated consts):

```rust
#![feature(inline_const)]

pub trait Test: Sized {
    const CONST: Self;
    fn static_ref() -> &'static Self {
        const { &Self::CONST }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f80980cb13c0d5cadf4a213d856de234).

```
error[E0492]: constants cannot refer to interior mutable data
 --> src/lib.rs:6:17
  |
6 |         const { &Self::CONST }
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this borrow of an interior mutable value may end up in the final value
```

See, static promotion is for *read-only* data. If the value contains `UnsafeCell` (or destructors), it cannot be promoted. Since we cannot guarantee the lack of that for arbitrary associated constant, it cannot be promoted.