# How to match a string against a static &str?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, match

I am writing a program that does probably a little bit too much with string processing. I moved most of the literal messages to constants; I'm not sure if that is the proper way in Rust, but I'm used to writing that in C.

I figured out that I cannot easily use my `static &str` inside a `match` expression. I can use the text itself, but cannot figure out how to do that properly.

I understand it's a compiler issue, but don't know how to write that construction properly in Rust style. Should I use enums instead of C-like static variables?

```
static SECTION_TEST: &str = "test result:";
static STATUS_TEST_OK: &str = "PASSED";

fn match_out(out: &String) -> bool {
    let s = &out[out.find(SECTION_TEST).unwrap() + SECTION_TEST.len()..];

    match s {
        STATUS_TEST_OK => {
            println!("Yes");
            true
        }
        _ => {
            println!("No");
            false
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0530]: match bindings cannot shadow statics
 --> src/lib.rs:8:9
  |
2 | static STATUS_TEST_OK: &str = "PASSED";
  | --------------------------------------- the static `STATUS_TEST_OK` is defined here
...
8 |         STATUS_TEST_OK => {
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot be named the same as a static
```

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: Hmm, yes in my code I used: &out[out.find(SECTION_TEST).unwrap()+SECTION_TEST.len()..] Just posted simplified version, which as you mentioned wont compile. Is that construction ok? I am just reading the link that you have sent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `const`ant instead of a static:

```
const STATUS_TEST_OK: &str = "PASSED";

fn match_out(s: &str) -> bool {
    match s {
        STATUS_TEST_OK => {
            println!("Yes");
            true
        }
        _ => {
            println!("No");
            false
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between a const variable and a static variable and which should I choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52751597/155423)
- [What is the difference between immutable and const variables in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37877381/155423)
- [How to match a String against string literals in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25383488/155423)
- [Why is this match pattern unreachable when using non-literal patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28225958/155423)

Comment: Thanks for the solution and references as well! Really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

For those unable to change the static to a const—although it's a little convoluted—another option is to use an if statement, which will return the `&str` (or whatever is defined) that lives in the static's NAME:

```
static STATUS_TEST_OK: &str = "PASSED";

fn match_out(s: &str) -> bool {

    match s {
        str if str == STATUS_TEST_OK => {
            println!("Yes");
            true
        }
        _ => {
            println!("No");
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The technical term for such `if` statement is a [match guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/match-expr.html#match-guards).