# Is the term immutable variable just a convention?

Tags: variables, rust

In Rust variables are immutable by default, i.e., they don't vary but are not constants (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877381/what-is-the-difference-between-immutable-and-const-variables-in-rust)).

Do they retain the name "*variable*" just by convention, or is there another reason why the term "*variable*" is maintained?

Comment: Mathematical variables are also stateless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be noted that the term `mut` in *Rust* was hotly debated before stabilization with some arguing that it should be called `excl` or `uniq`. The matter is that the `mut` in in `let mut x` and `&mut x` are two completely different things.

`let mut x` declares that `x` is mutable, in the sense that it can be re-assigned, but also that one can take a `&mut` reference of it; which is best called an **exclusive** or **unique** reference. It is quite possible in Rust in some cases to mutate through a **shared** reference in the case of `std::cell::Cell`, for instance, and not all operations that require an exclusive reference involve mutation. An operation that requires an exclusive reference is simply one that would be unsafe with a shared one; `Cell` is designed in such a way that it is not, by strictly controlling under what conditions mutation can occur.

In theory, the two functions of `let mut x` could have different keywords, but they are compressed into one for simplicity. *Rust* could in theory be designed with `mut` and `excl` being different keywords, and allowing for `let excl x`, which would be a variable wherefrom one could take an exclusive reference, but not mutate.

One can also have variables that are not declared with `mut`, in particular in function calls. In a signature like `fn func ( x : u32 )`, x is not mutable, but it is variable, because it a different `x` can be passed every single time.

The `let mut x` type of "mutable" is purely a lint and, in theory, unnecessary for *Rust* to work — any currently working *Rust* program will continue to work if all non-mutable variables be made mutable. It's simply considered bad practice to do so and the compiler will warn the programmer whenever he make a variable mutable that isn't necessary to be mutable; this helps catching unintended bugs. This is absolutely not the case with exclusive and shared references, which are necessary to be distinguished and more than just a lint.

Comment: *In a signature like `fn func ( x : u32 )`, x is not mutable, but it is variable, because it a different x can be passed every single time.* I think this is the essential observation. The mutable/unique distinction is interesting, but tangential.

Comment: Please will you elaborate on a *lint* (in the final paragraph)? 
Also @trentcl has pointed out what I agree to be the key point.

Comment: @darkacts Yes, that is indeed the quintessence of a variable in a mathematical function; they can be instanced with any different value for a given instance thereof, but they are not mutated in sequences because they are stateless and timeless; a "lint" is a term used for parts of code that are not necessary for correctness, but enable better diagnostics and catch errors — quite a few languages have such features.

Answer (score 2):

Here "variable" means "factor involved in computation" not "varying". This is from the mathematical principle where expressions like *f(x)* include *x*, a variable, as a part of the equation.

In Rust, like with other languages, you'll need variables (e.g. input) that affects how the program runs, otherwise your program would only ever behave in a singular, specific way, producing the same output each time.

You'll need to think of what variables change *during* processing and which do not. Those that do not need to change do not need to be declared mutable.

Regardless of if or when they change, they're still considered *variables*.

In C++ you'll have things like `const int x` which is a constant (read-only) variable, so the term can take on all sorts of specific meanings.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the term immutable variable just a convention?

By definition every... definition of a word is a convention, language, meaning of the word, change by time, is unique for every people that live, you can take 100 peoples and end with 100 difference definition of 1 word. That why we often start scientific paper by defining word that could be miss understand in the paper. Trying to clarify as much as possible. Rust does not differs that why we have [The Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/)

We have a specific section for [variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/variables.html)

> A variable is a component of a stack frame, either a named function
>   parameter, an anonymous temporary, or a named local variable.
>
> A local variable (or stack-local allocation) holds a value directly,
>   allocated within the stack's memory. The value is a part of the stack
>   frame.
>
> Local variables are immutable unless declared otherwise. For example:
>   let mut x = ....
>
> Function parameters are immutable unless declared with mut. The mut
>   keyword applies only to the following parameter. For example: |mut x,
>   y| and fn f(mut x: Box, y: Box) declare one mutable variable
>   x and one immutable variable y.
>
> Local variables are not initialized when allocated. Instead, the
>   entire frame worth of local variables are allocated, on frame-entry,
>   in an uninitialized state. Subsequent statements within a function may
>   or may not initialize the local variables. Local variables can be used
>   only after they have been initialized through all reachable control
>   flow paths.

So there is not much to add, variable in rust is clearly defined, it doesn't matter if your definition doesn't match or you find a definition of variable that doesn't match Rust one. In the context of Rust, variable is that. If you want to ask about opinion about this choice then it's off topic as opinion oriented. But, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable) definition make Rust definition quite standard both from mathematics view than computer science:

> Variable (computer science), a symbolic name associated with a value and whose associated value **may** be changed
>
> Variable (mathematics), a symbol that represents a quantity in a mathematical expression, as used in many sciences

Comment: So is the following statement correct?
*Rust uses the term variable for no reason other than that is how it is defined withinn the documentation (which is analogous to it's definition in computer science and mathematics).*

Comment: @darkacts No, the is historical and origin reason but it doesn't matter in the end.